# How to get result from two tables without a join

Tags: sql

..first table contain

```
id,name,age..
```

2nd table contain

```
id , salary ...
```

how to combine them without a join?

Comment: What do you really want to achieve? Why not just move the salary column to the first table?

Comment: No offense intended, but this question isn't very useful. What are you trying to do?

Comment: i need the both id as a primary key..and i need to merge ....without join

Answer (score 2):

Depend on the amount of columns you need from the second table.

If its not much, then you can use a correlated query to get this results, but each column you need means another correlated query:

```
SELECT t.*,
       (SELECT s.salary FROM 2nd_Table s
        WHERE t.id = s.id) as salary,
       (SELECT s.OtherColumn FROM 2nd_Table s
        WHERE t.id = s.id) as OtherColumn ,
FROM 1st_table t
```

Comment: can u give me a detailed code explanation....like create,insert and merge....pleasee...

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sub-query to get result from multiple tables without any join relationship.

```
select id, name, age, (select salary from tbl2 where id = 2) as salary 
from tbl1;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do this.

1. Perform a nested query.

   ```
   select id, name, age from table1 where id in (select id from table2);
   ```

   But in this approach, you can only access columns of first table.
2. Create view based on your requirement.

   In this approach, you can create views with columns from multiple tables as per your requirements and then simply query over it in one go.

   ```
   create view v as (
       select t1.id, t1.name, t1.age, t2.salary
       from table1 t1
       join table2 t2
       on  t1.id = t2.id
   );
   ```

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, ..., b.salery, ..
FROM table1 a, table2 b
WHERE a.id = b.id
```

Simple as that